# Please help about regular expression

Tags: regex

What's wrong with this expression?

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(([\''\-][a-zA-Z])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$
```

I want to allow alpha characters with space,-, and ' characters

for example O'neal;Jackson-Peter, Mary Jane

Comment: Provide examples of what you want it to match and what you don't want it to match

Comment: I want it to match alpha characters with space,-, and ' characters

Comment: What language? It may be that you don't need to escape the ' and the - in the second clause.

Comment: C#,I use this for a regular expression validation control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is all you need:

```
^[a-zA-Z' -]+$
```

The important thing is that the "-" is the last character in the group, otherwise it'd be interpreted as a range (unless you escaped it with "\")

How you actually input that expression as a string in your target language is different depending on the language. For C#, I usually use "@" strings, like so:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z' -]+$");
```

Comment: Your regex matches the empty string.

Comment: @too much php: not any more :) though if this is for ASP.NET, you should be using a separate `RequiredFieldValidator` control, since (by default) `RegularExpressionValidator` controls aren't called on empty fields anyway...

Answer (score 2):

This will match any string made up of at least one character, which can be alpha characters, hyphen or the single quote mark:

```
^[a-zA-Z-\']+$
```

This will also include empty strings:

```
^[a-zA-Z-\']*$
```

If it needs to begin and end with alpha characters (as names do):

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z-\']*[a-zA-Z]$
```

Comment: Are you sure that last hyphen won't be interpreted as a range instead? It'd be safer to put it at the end. Also, while it's unlikely, you may well have a one-letter name, so you might want to toss a `?` just before the `$`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
^[a-zA-Z '\-,]*$
```